# all routes returning 'get' error on production when page is refreshed - nodejs, express api with webpack and reactjs client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

I have currently configured webpack to compile my react app and nodejs as the server with express middleware.

Everytime I refresh a route on production e.g /chefs a get error is returned.

Here is my server.js configuration:

```
authRoutes(router);
reservationRoutes(router);

// Use our router configuration when we call /
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('dist'), router);
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
  });
} else {
  app.use('/', router);
}

// starts the server and listens for requests
app.listen(config.port, () => {
  console.log(`api running on port ${config.port}`);
});

// db config
mongoose.connect(config.database, {
  useMongoClient: true,
});
```

and here is the webpack configuration:

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/client/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './client/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    inline: true,
    contentBase: './client',
    port: 8080,
    proxy: { '/api/**': { target: 'http://localhost:3000', secure: false } }
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader', query: {presets: ['es2015','react'], plugins: ['transform-es2015-destructuring', 'transform-object-rest-spread']}},
        {test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.svg$|\.png$/i, loader: 'file-loader?name=/images/[name].[ext]'},
        {test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader','resolve-url-loader']},
        {test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader','postcss-loader', 'sass-loader','resolve-url-loader']}
        ]
  },
  plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig]
};
```

Here is the error log, it's a 404:

```
2018-01-16T11:13:48.917673+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/chefs" host=testapp.herokuapp.com request_id=ae107e20-d796-485b-8ffb-0a4f6759e876 fwd="86.169.30.58" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=754 protocol=https
```

Note: All api routes begin with 'api/'. However, all routes, expect the home index route return an 'get' error when the page is refresh and this only happens in production.

Any help?

Comment: Can you post the error logs?

Comment: done, the log is a simple 404. Basically when refreshing the browser the get request is still directed at the api and not served from the compiled client routes.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this part of the code was the problem:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('dist'), router);
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
  });
} else {
  app.use('/', router);
}
```

where the only route that was being redirected to the index.html was '/'. The fix was to add * after the slash taking all routes that arent found on the api.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('dist'), router);
  app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
  });
} else {
  app.use('/', router);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clients routes are handled by your index.html, so `/index.html#/chefs` should work, you can use [HashRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter) to generate this kind of urls.

If you want `/chefs` to work, you must send all non `/api` traffic to `index.html` and use [BrowserRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter)